# Play sound upon clicking, HTML / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, web

I want to play certain sounds upon clicking certain div's. It's not working. It does however play all the sounds simultaneously when I add 4 * xTone.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay'); (one for each of 4 tones). So, that narrows it down somewhat I suppose. Here is my code:

```
<body>

    <div id="header">Header</div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>

        var eTone = document.createElement('audio');
        eTone.setAttribute('src', 'eTone.mp3');

        $('#eTone').click(function(){
            eTone.play();
        });

        var fTone = document.createElement('audio');
        fTone.setAttribute('src', 'fTone.mp3');

        $('#fTone').click(function(){
            fTone.play();
        });

        var gTone = document.createElement('audio');
        gTone.setAttribute('src', 'gTone.mp3');

        $('#gTone').click(function(){
            gTone.play();
        });

        var aTone = document.createElement('audio');
        aTone.setAttribute('src', 'aTone.mp3');

        $('#aTone').click(function(){
            aTone.play();
        });

    </script>

    <table id="musiccloud">
        <tr>
            <td><div id="eTone" class="rain"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div id="fTone" class="rain"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div id="gTone" class="rain"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div id="aTone" class="rain"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

What do I do to make the 4 different tones play when each of their div's are clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used something like this (calling the functions inside the div.click):

```
<script>
function play(cancion){
        var can = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[cancion];
        can.play();
    }
function stop(){
        can = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
        can.pause();
        can = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[1];
        can.pause();
        can = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[2];
        can.pause();
    }

</script>
<audio id="song1">
    <source src="song1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="song1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
<audio id="song2">
    <source src="song2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="song2.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

Also if you want the multimedia to be compatible with more web explorers you should try jplayer